# Is there a way to share common configuration using Paste Deploy?

Tags: python, pyramid, web-deployment, paste

This is a pretty simple idea conceptually. In terms of specifics, I'm working with a pretty generic Kotti installation, where I'm customizing some pages / templates.

Much of my configuration is shared between a production and development server. Currently, these settings are included in two separate ini files. It would be nice to DRY this configuration, with common settings in one place.

I'm quite open to this happening in python or an an ini file / section (or perhaps a third, yet-to-be-considered place). I think it's equivalent to use a [DEFAULT] section, or pass dictionaries to `loadapp` via `global_conf`, but that seems to be processed in a squirrelly way. For example, Kotti thinks I've properly set sqlalchemy.url, but sqlalchemy iteself fails on `url = opts.pop('url')`. Moreover, since Kotti defines some default settings, Paste doesn't end up searching for them in the global_conf (e.g., `kotti_configurators`).

I **don't** like the idea of passing in a large dict for `%(var)s` substitution, as it requires effectively renaming all of the shared variables.

In my initial experiments with Paste Deploy, it demands a "main" section in each ini file. So, I don't think I can just use a `use = config:shared.ini` line. But that's conceptually close to what I'd like to do.

Is there a way to explicitly (and properly) include settings from DEFAULT or `global_conf`? Or perhaps do this programmatically with python on the results of loadapp?

Comment: *So, I don't think I can just use (...)* Don't guess - just try it.

Comment: Just to be clear, I did try a lot of things. The "don't think" applies to a general approach, which I may not yet fully understand. Your comment is annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, Kotti thinks I've properly set sqlalchemy.url, but sqlalchemy iteself fails on url = opts.pop('url').

If you think something is odd and you're asking on SO it'd be wise to show a stacktrace and an example of what you tried to do.

Kotti gets its settings the same as any pyramid app. Your entry point (`def main(global_conf, **settings)` usually) is passed the `global_conf` and `settings` dictionary. You're then responsible for fixing that up and shuffling it off into the configurator.

For various reasons PasteDeploy keeps the `global_conf` separate from the settings, thus you're responsible for merging them if you wish.

```
[DEFAULT]
foo = bar

[app:main]
use = egg:myapp#main
baz = xyz

def main(global_conf, **app_settings):
    settings = global_conf
    settings.update(app_settings)
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('kotti')
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

Comment: Awesome. In this particular case, there are so many different ways I tried approaching things that it was hard for me to wrap it up in one specific example / stack trace. Despite my shortcomings here, though, this sounds like the right track. Thanks, and I'll report back on whether this gets me the rest of the way!

Comment: Sharing settings by means of `[DEFAULT]` section is possible as long as all apps are defined in the same ini file, right? Is it possible to have common settings in one ini file and reference/include these settings from separate ini files specific to applications?

Comment: Well you only get one default section. So if an app section in `A.ini` inherits from a section in another file named `B.ini`, then the default section in `B.ini` is not considered. At least that's how I understand the inheritance part (it only works on a section-basis).